# Replacement for tray icons in 13.04?

Tags: unity, indicator, system-tray

According to [this posting here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/unity-notification-area-systray.html), 13.04 will finally disable the support for tray icons by taking away the idea of *whitelisting* applications for tray icon usage.

My problem is that I have to use several applications that don't care about unity (for example: IBM sametime and Lotus notes; Symantec Antivirus).

Please note that these are all "true" Linux versions of the corresponding products. I can't say if they are supported officially on Ubuntu; but they run fine ... without using Wine for example. So, that Wine tray icons still work doesn't help these applications.

Just wondering: is there any back door that I am not aware of? Like, some generic indicator that could be configured to wrap around the no longer supported tray icons?

Comment: You should ask this again when 13.04 is released. I read on some websites people making the same argument but the main comment was: BM sametime, Lotus notes; Symantec Antivirus should alter their software so get in line with Ubuntu's method.

Comment: Lot's more here: [New Unity, whitelist disabled = bad](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113769).

Comment: This issue is subject to this lengthy bug-report - should be interesting to see how this pan's out: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/974480